# Inheriting from a JFrame class to another class and using the variables

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm new in java, and I'm working on a program using GUI. My problem is that I'm reaching **1000 Line** and this is stressful because all my code are in one file. I'm not liking this. So I research the internet about Inheritance. However, I'm not sure how this can help me in my problem because all what I know about Inheritance that Inherit everything in the parent class. However, when I try to use a variables in the child class I can't for example let say that I have in the parent class something like this:

JButton getButton = new JButton("Enter");

now when I go to the child class. I want to Inherit and use this variable so I can use the ActionListener it's not working.

So could any tell me what I'm I doing wrong here, or this not the right way to do it ?

Thank you everyone before and after.

Here is some of my code:

```
    public class H_Store extends JFrame {

    private JCheckBox groundMeatCheckBox;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    H_Store frame = new H_Store();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public H_Store() {
        super("Hussin Store");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 1378, 657);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(mnHelp);
        mainPane = new JPanel();
        mainPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(mainPane);
        mainPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 0));


        JPanel meetPanel = new JPanel();
        meetPanel.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        mainPane.add(meetPanel);

        JLabel meatLabel = new JLabel("*Meat*");
        meatLabel.setBounds(546, 101, 79, 77);
        meatLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        meatLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 25));

        ///////////////////

        JCheckBox groundMeatCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Ground ");

        groundMeatCheckBox.setBounds(8, 71, 113, 25);
        groundMeatCheckBox.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        groundMeatCheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        meetPanel.setLayout(null);
        meetPanel.add(meatLabel);
        meetPanel.add(groundMeatCheckBox);

        JCheckBox chuckMeatCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Chuck");
        chuckMeatCheckBox.setBounds(8, 126, 113, 25);
        meetPanel.add(chuckMeatCheckBox);

        JCheckBox ribMeatCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Rib");
        ribMeatCheckBox.setBounds(8, 101, 113, 25);
        meetPanel.add(ribMeatCheckBox);

        JCheckBox steakMeatCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Steak");
        steakMeatCheckBox.setBounds(8, 153, 120, 25);
        meetPanel.add(steakMeatCheckBox);

        JCheckBox flankMeatCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Flank");
        flankMeatCheckBox.setBounds(8, 183, 113, 25);
        meetPanel.add(flankMeatCheckBox);

        JCheckBox roundMeatCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Round");
        roundMeatCheckBox.setBounds(8, 213, 113, 25);
        meetPanel.add(roundMeatCheckBox);

        ground_M_QTextField = new JTextField(10);
        ground_M_QTextField.setText("0");
        ground_M_QTextField.setBounds(155, 76, 18, 16);
        meetPanel.add(ground_M_QTextField);
        ground_M_QTextField.setColumns(10);

        chuck_M_QTextField = new JTextField();
        chuck_M_QTextField.setText("0");
        chuck_M_QTextField.setColumns(10);
        chuck_M_QTextField.setBounds(155, 105, 18, 16);
        meetPanel.add(chuck_M_QTextField);

        rib_M_QTextField = new JTextField();
        rib_M_QTextField.setText("0");
        rib_M_QTextField.setColumns(10);
        rib_M_QTextField.setBounds(155, 130, 18, 16);
        meetPanel.add(rib_M_QTextField);

        steak_M_QTextField = new JTextField();
        steak_M_QTextField.setText("0");
        steak_M_QTextField.setColumns(10);
        steak_M_QTextField.setBounds(155, 157, 18, 16);
        meetPanel.add(steak_M_QTextField);

        flank_M_QTextField = new JTextField();
        flank_M_QTextField.setText("0");
        flank_M_QTextField.setColumns(10);
        flank_M_QTextField.setBounds(155, 187, 18, 16);
        meetPanel.add(flank_M_QTextField);

        round_M_QTextField = new JTextField();
        round_M_QTextField.setText("0");
        round_M_QTextField.setColumns(10);
        round_M_QTextField.setBounds(155, 217, 18, 16);
        meetPanel.add(round_M_QTextField);

        JLabel lblType = new JLabel("Type:");
        lblType.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lblType.setBounds(8, 46, 44, 16);
        meetPanel.add(lblType);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Quantity:");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(155, 46, 61, 16);
        meetPanel.add(lblNewLabel);

        ground_M_WTextField = new JTextField();
        ground_M_WTextField.setText("0.00");
        ground_M_WTextField.setColumns(10);
        ground_M_WTextField.setBounds(291, 73, 36, 16);
        meetPanel.add(ground_M_WTextField);

        chuck_M_WTextField = new JTextField();
        chuck_M_WTextField.setText("0.00");
        chuck_M_WTextField.setColumns(10);
        chuck_M_WTextField.setBounds(291, 105, 36, 16);
        meetPanel.add(chuck_M_WTextField);

        rib_M_WTextField = new JTextField();
        rib_M_WTextField.setText("0.00");
        rib_M_WTextField.setColumns(10);
        rib_M_WTextField.setBounds(291, 130, 36, 16);
        meetPanel.add(rib_M_WTextField);

        steak_M_WTextField = new JTextField();
        steak_M_WTextField.setText("0.00");
        steak_M_WTextField.setColumns(10);
        steak_M_WTextField.setBounds(291, 157, 36, 16);
        meetPanel.add(steak_M_WTextField);

        flank_M_WTextField = new JTextField();
        flank_M_WTextField.setText("0.00");
        flank_M_WTextField.setColumns(10);
        flank_M_WTextField.setBounds(291, 187, 36, 16);
        meetPanel.add(flank_M_WTextField);

        round_M_WTextField = new JTextField();
        round_M_WTextField.setText("0.00");
        round_M_WTextField.setColumns(10);
        round_M_WTextField.setBounds(291, 217, 36, 16);
        meetPanel.add(round_M_WTextField);

        JLabel lblWeightlp = new JLabel("(LP) Weight: ");
        lblWeightlp.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lblWeightlp.setBounds(291, 46, 86, 16);
        meetPanel.add(lblWeightlp);

        at_M_QTextField = new JTextField();
        at_M_QTextField.setText("0");
        at_M_QTextField.setColumns(10);
        at_M_QTextField.setBounds(155, 251, 18, 16);
        meetPanel.add(at_M_QTextField);

        at_M_WTextField = new JTextField();
        at_M_WTextField.setText("0.00");
        at_M_WTextField.setColumns(10);
        at_M_WTextField.setBounds(291, 251, 36, 16);
        meetPanel.add(at_M_WTextField);

        at_meat_TextField = new JTextField();
        at_meat_TextField.setText("Another Type..");
        at_meat_TextField.setColumns(10);
        at_meat_TextField.setBounds(8, 250, 98, 24);
        meetPanel.add(at_meat_TextField);

        lblPrice = new JLabel("(LP)Price:");
        lblPrice.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lblPrice.setBounds(446, 46, 73, 16);
        meetPanel.add(lblPrice);

        ground_M_PTextField = new JTextField();
        ground_M_PTextField.setText("0.00");
        ground_M_PTextField.setColumns(10);
        ground_M_PTextField.setBounds(445, 71, 36, 16);
        meetPanel.add(ground_M_PTextField);

        rib_M_PTextField = new JTextField();
        rib_M_PTextField.setText("0.00");
        rib_M_PTextField.setColumns(10);
        rib_M_PTextField.setBounds(445, 103, 36, 16);
        meetPanel.add(rib_M_PTextField);

        chuck_M_PTextField = new JTextField();
        chuck_M_PTextField.setText("0.00");
        chuck_M_PTextField.setColumns(10);
        chuck_M_PTextField.setBounds(445, 128, 36, 16);
        meetPanel.add(chuck_M_PTextField);

        steak_M_PTextField = new JTextField();
        steak_M_PTextField.setText("0.00");
        steak_M_PTextField.setColumns(10);
        steak_M_PTextField.setBounds(445, 155, 36, 16);
        meetPanel.add(steak_M_PTextField);

        flank_M_PTextField = new JTextField();
        flank_M_PTextField.setText("0.00");
        flank_M_PTextField.setColumns(10);
        flank_M_PTextField.setBounds(445, 185, 36, 16);
        meetPanel.add(flank_M_PTextField);

        round_M_PTextField = new JTextField();
        round_M_PTextField.setText("0.00");
        round_M_PTextField.setColumns(10);
        round_M_PTextField.setBounds(445, 215, 36, 16);
        meetPanel.add(round_M_PTextField);

        at_M_PTextField = new JTextField();
        at_M_PTextField.setText("0.00");
        at_M_PTextField.setColumns(10);
        at_M_PTextField.setBounds(445, 249, 36, 16);
        meetPanel.add(at_M_PTextField);

        JPanel chikenPanel = new JPanel();
        chikenPanel.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, Color.BLUE, null, null));
        mainPane.add(chikenPanel);
        chikenPanel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblChiken = new JLabel("*Chiken*");
        lblChiken.setBounds(543, 104, 120, 77);
        lblChiken.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        chikenPanel.add(lblChiken);

        JCheckBox whole_C_CheckBox = new JCheckBox("Whole");
        whole_C_CheckBox.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        whole_C_CheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        whole_C_CheckBox.setBounds(12, 66, 113, 25);
        chikenPanel.add(whole_C_CheckBox);

        JCheckBox half_C_CheckBox = new JCheckBox("Half");
        half_C_CheckBox.setBounds(12, 96, 113, 25);
        chikenPanel.add(half_C_CheckBox);

        JCheckBox breast_C_CheckBox = new JCheckBox("Breast");
        breast_C_CheckBox.setBounds(12, 126, 113, 25);
        chikenPanel.add(breast_C_CheckBox);

        JCheckBox wings_C_CheckBox = new JCheckBox("Wings");
        wings_C_CheckBox.setBounds(12, 156, 120, 25);
        chikenPanel.add(wings_C_CheckBox);

        JCheckBox liver_C_CheckBox = new JCheckBox("Liver");
        liver_C_CheckBox.setBounds(12, 186, 113, 25);
        chikenPanel.add(liver_C_CheckBox);

        JCheckBox heart_C_CheckBox = new JCheckBox("Heart");
        heart_C_CheckBox.setBounds(12, 216, 113, 25);
        chikenPanel.add(heart_C_CheckBox);

        textField_13 = new JTextField();
        textField_13.setText("0");
        textField_13.setColumns(10);
        textField_13.setBounds(170, 71, 25, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_13);

        textField_14 = new JTextField();
        textField_14.setText("0");
        textField_14.setColumns(10);
        textField_14.setBounds(170, 97, 25, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_14);

        textField_15 = new JTextField();
        textField_15.setText("0");
        textField_15.setColumns(10);
        textField_15.setBounds(170, 130, 25, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_15);

        textField_16 = new JTextField();
        textField_16.setText("0");
        textField_16.setColumns(10);
        textField_16.setBounds(170, 160, 25, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_16);

        textField_17 = new JTextField();
        textField_17.setText("0");
        textField_17.setColumns(10);
        textField_17.setBounds(170, 190, 25, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_17);

        textField_18 = new JTextField();
        textField_18.setText("0");
        textField_18.setColumns(10);
        textField_18.setBounds(170, 220, 25, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_18);

        textField_19 = new JTextField();
        textField_19.setText("0.00");
        textField_19.setColumns(10);
        textField_19.setBounds(320, 220, 38, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_19);

        textField_20 = new JTextField();
        textField_20.setText("0.00");
        textField_20.setColumns(10);
        textField_20.setBounds(320, 190, 38, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_20);

        textField_21 = new JTextField();
        textField_21.setText("0.00");
        textField_21.setColumns(10);
        textField_21.setBounds(320, 157, 38, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_21);

        textField_22 = new JTextField();
        textField_22.setText("0.00");
        textField_22.setColumns(10);
        textField_22.setBounds(320, 130, 38, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_22);

        textField_23 = new JTextField();
        textField_23.setText("0.00");
        textField_23.setColumns(10);
        textField_23.setBounds(320, 100, 38, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_23);

        textField_24 = new JTextField();
        textField_24.setText("0.00");
        textField_24.setColumns(10);
        textField_24.setBounds(320, 71, 38, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_24);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Type:");
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        label.setBounds(12, 41, 56, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(label);

        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Quantity:");
        label_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        label_1.setBounds(170, 41, 75, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(label_1);

        JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("(LP) Weight: ");
        label_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        label_2.setBounds(320, 41, 92, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(label_2);

        textField_12 = new JTextField();
        textField_12.setText("Another Type..");
        textField_12.setColumns(10);
        textField_12.setBounds(12, 250, 99, 24);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_12);

        textField_34 = new JTextField();
        textField_34.setText("0");
        textField_34.setColumns(10);
        textField_34.setBounds(170, 251, 25, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_34);

        textField_35 = new JTextField();
        textField_35.setText("0.00");
        textField_35.setColumns(10);
        textField_35.setBounds(320, 251, 38, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_35);

        label_5 = new JLabel("Price:");
        label_5.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        label_5.setBounds(477, 41, 43, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(label_5);

        textField_7 = new JTextField();
        textField_7.setText("0.00");
        textField_7.setColumns(10);
        textField_7.setBounds(477, 71, 36, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_7);

        textField_8 = new JTextField();
        textField_8.setText("0.00");
        textField_8.setColumns(10);
        textField_8.setBounds(477, 100, 36, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_8);

        textField_9 = new JTextField();
        textField_9.setText("0.00");
        textField_9.setColumns(10);
        textField_9.setBounds(476, 130, 36, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_9);

        textField_10 = new JTextField();
        textField_10.setText("0.00");
        textField_10.setColumns(10);
        textField_10.setBounds(476, 160, 36, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_10);

        textField_11 = new JTextField();
        textField_11.setText("0.00");
        textField_11.setColumns(10);
        textField_11.setBounds(477, 190, 36, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_11);

        textField_25 = new JTextField();
        textField_25.setText("0.00");
        textField_25.setColumns(10);
        textField_25.setBounds(477, 220, 36, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_25);

        textField_32 = new JTextField();
        textField_32.setText("0.00");
        textField_32.setColumns(10);
        textField_32.setBounds(477, 254, 36, 16);
        chikenPanel.add(textField_32);

        JPanel otherThingsPanel = new JPanel();
        otherThingsPanel.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        mainPane.add(otherThingsPanel);
        otherThingsPanel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblOtherThings = new JLabel("*Other Things*");
        lblOtherThings.setBounds(421, 117, 176, 42);
        lblOtherThings.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        otherThingsPanel.add(lblOtherThings);

        JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("Type:");
        label_3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        label_3.setBounds(16, 46, 65, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(label_3);

        JCheckBox chckbxCheese = new JCheckBox("Cheese");
        chckbxCheese.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        chckbxCheese.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        chckbxCheese.setBounds(12, 71, 113, 25);
        otherThingsPanel.add(chckbxCheese);

        JCheckBox chckbxBread = new JCheckBox("Bread");
        chckbxBread.setBounds(12, 101, 113, 25);
        otherThingsPanel.add(chckbxBread);

        JCheckBox chckbxRice = new JCheckBox("Rice");
        chckbxRice.setBounds(12, 131, 113, 25);
        otherThingsPanel.add(chckbxRice);

        JCheckBox chckbxBeefBurger = new JCheckBox("Burger ");
        chckbxBeefBurger.setBounds(12, 161, 120, 25);
        otherThingsPanel.add(chckbxBeefBurger);

        JCheckBox chckbxChickenBurger = new JCheckBox("Kebab");
        chckbxChickenBurger.setBounds(12, 191, 113, 25);
        otherThingsPanel.add(chckbxChickenBurger);

        JCheckBox chckbxFalafel = new JCheckBox("Falafel");
        chckbxFalafel.setBounds(12, 221, 113, 25);
        otherThingsPanel.add(chckbxFalafel);

        textField_26 = new JTextField();
        textField_26.setText("0");
        textField_26.setColumns(10);
        textField_26.setBounds(165, 225, 25, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(textField_26);

        textField_27 = new JTextField();
        textField_27.setText("0");
        textField_27.setColumns(10);
        textField_27.setBounds(165, 195, 25, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(textField_27);

        textField_28 = new JTextField();
        textField_28.setText("0");
        textField_28.setColumns(10);
        textField_28.setBounds(165, 162, 25, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(textField_28);

        textField_29 = new JTextField();
        textField_29.setText("0");
        textField_29.setColumns(10);
        textField_29.setBounds(165, 132, 25, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(textField_29);

        textField_30 = new JTextField();
        textField_30.setText("0");
        textField_30.setColumns(10);
        textField_30.setBounds(165, 102, 25, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(textField_30);

        textField_31 = new JTextField();
        textField_31.setText("0");
        textField_31.setColumns(10);
        textField_31.setBounds(165, 76, 25, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(textField_31);

        JLabel label_4 = new JLabel("Quantity:");
        label_4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        label_4.setBounds(165, 46, 65, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(label_4);

        otherThings_AnotherTypeTextField = new JTextField();
        otherThings_AnotherTypeTextField.setText("Another Type..");
        otherThings_AnotherTypeTextField.setColumns(10);
        otherThings_AnotherTypeTextField.setBounds(16, 250, 93, 24);
        otherThingsPanel.add(otherThings_AnotherTypeTextField);

        textField_36 = new JTextField();
        textField_36.setText("0");
        textField_36.setColumns(10);
        textField_36.setBounds(165, 254, 25, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(textField_36);

        label_6 = new JLabel("Price:");
        label_6.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        label_6.setBounds(310, 46, 56, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(label_6);

        textField_33 = new JTextField();
        textField_33.setText("0.00");
        textField_33.setColumns(10);
        textField_33.setBounds(309, 71, 36, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(textField_33);

        textField_37 = new JTextField();
        textField_37.setText("0.00");
        textField_37.setColumns(10);
        textField_37.setBounds(309, 103, 36, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(textField_37);

        textField_38 = new JTextField();
        textField_38.setText("0.00");
        textField_38.setColumns(10);
        textField_38.setBounds(309, 128, 36, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(textField_38);

        textField_39 = new JTextField();
        textField_39.setText("0.00");
        textField_39.setColumns(10);
        textField_39.setBounds(309, 155, 36, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(textField_39);

        textField_40 = new JTextField();
        textField_40.setText("0.00");
        textField_40.setColumns(10);
        textField_40.setBounds(309, 185, 36, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(textField_40);

        textField_41 = new JTextField();
        textField_41.setText("0.00");
        textField_41.setColumns(10);
        textField_41.setBounds(309, 215, 36, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(textField_41);

        textField_42 = new JTextField();
        textField_42.setText("0.00");
        textField_42.setColumns(10);
        textField_42.setBounds(309, 249, 36, 16);
        otherThingsPanel.add(textField_42);

        JPanel calculationPanel = new JPanel();
        calculationPanel.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        mainPane.add(calculationPanel);
        calculationPanel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblCalculation = new JLabel("*Calculation*");
        lblCalculation.setBounds(212, 12, 148, 29);
        lblCalculation.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        calculationPanel.add(lblCalculation);

        // Calculation everything

        JButton calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        calculateButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());

        calculateButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        calculateButton.setBounds(340, 177, 313, 97);
        calculationPanel.add(calculateButton);

        txtrWriteYourComment = new JTextArea();
        txtrWriteYourComment.setRows(1);
        txtrWriteYourComment.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        txtrWriteYourComment.setText("Write Your Comment here.....");
        txtrWriteYourComment.setBounds(12, 54, 641, 111);
        calculationPanel.add(txtrWriteYourComment);

        getProfitJButton = new JButton("Get Profit");
        getProfitJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Profit");
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                frame2.setSize(350,200);
                frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);          
                profitPanel = new JPanel();
                profitPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
                setContentPane(profitPanel);
                profitPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 0));
                frame2.getContentPane().add(profitPanel);               


                profitFileButton = new JButton("Porfit File");

                profitFileTextField = new JTextField();


                getProfitJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        profitJFileChooser = new JFileChooser();                
                        profitJFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);                
                        File f = profitJFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                        String fileName = f.getAbsolutePath();
                        profitFileTextField.setText(fileName);      

                    }
                });

                profitPanel.add(profitFileButton);
                profitPanel.add(profitFileTextField);

                sellFileButtton = new JButton("Sell File");
                profitPanel.add(sellFileButtton);


            }
        });
        getProfitJButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        getProfitJButton.setBounds(12, 177, 316, 97);
        calculationPanel.add(getProfitJButton);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////

        theholder holder = new theholder();
        groundMeatCheckBox.addItemListener(holder);



    }

    private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener{

        // vairbles for the ground Meat check box
        private double total_GM;
        private double weightPrice_1;
        private String stringQ;
        private String stringW;
        private String stringP;
        private int meat_Q1;
        private double meat_W1;
        private double meat_P1;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            total_GM = 0;

            // The ground Meat check box calculation  

                stringQ = ground_M_QTextField.getText();
                meat_Q1 = Integer.parseInt(stringQ);

                stringW = ground_M_WTextField.getText();
                meat_W1 = Double.parseDouble(stringW);

                stringP = ground_M_PTextField.getText();
                meat_P1 = Double.parseDouble(stringP);

                weightPrice_1 = meat_W1 * meat_P1;
                total_GM += weightPrice_1  * meat_Q1;


                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, total_GM + "\n" + s);


        }

    }

}
```

What I want to do exactly is to take the last code into another class or do something with so I can use it in the Parent class, in other word any math I want outside the Parent class.

Note: I mean this code

```
private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener{

            // vairbles for the ground Meat check box
            private double total_GM;
            private double weightPrice_1;
            private String stringQ;
            private String stringW;
            private String stringP;
            private int meat_Q1;
            private double meat_W1;
            private double meat_P1;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                total_GM = 0;

                // The ground Meat check box calculation  

                    stringQ = ground_M_QTextField.getText();
                    meat_Q1 = Integer.parseInt(stringQ);

                    stringW = ground_M_WTextField.getText();
                    meat_W1 = Double.parseDouble(stringW);

                    stringP = ground_M_PTextField.getText();
                    meat_P1 = Double.parseDouble(stringP);

                    weightPrice_1 = meat_W1 * meat_P1;
                    total_GM += weightPrice_1  * meat_Q1;


                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, total_GM + "\n" + s);


            }

        }
```

Comment: Hi, can you post a few examples of your code and maybe I can help you...

Answer (score 5):

You state:

> My problem is that I'm reaching 1000 Line and this is stressful because all my code are in one file. I'm not liking this.

You are quite right to not like this and to try to improve this set up as this type of program will be a monster to maintain, debug and enhance..

You then state:

> Inheriting from a JFrame class to another class and using the variables

This is not what inheritance is for as objects of the child class will be a completely distinct entities from objects of the parent class, so you will not want to do this.

Instead

- Remember to strive to enhance by composition rather than inheritance, meaning have classes *contain* fields of other classes.
- Avoid using the static modifier to make global-like variables as this will hog-tie your code.
- try to break out logical parts of your program from the visual, the GUI parts,
- And split up each specific logical part and each major GUI part into its own class.
- make sure all classes have decent setter and getter methods,
- and that the classes are written so that they communicate well with each other.
- A Swing specific recommendation is for you to avoid extending JFrame.
- Instead gear your Swing GUI's towards creating JPanels, panels which can be placed anywhere you want them, including in JFrames, JApplets, JDialogs, JOptionPanes, inside of other JPanels, in JTabbedPanes, as "cards" in a CardLayout-using JPanel,....
- This will greatly improve the flexibility and enhance-ability of your program.

For more specific help, please feel free to provide more details about your program and its code.

---

**Edit**

Sorry to be blunt, but you've come for advice on your code, and I have to inform you that it has some significant problems including:

- it contains more quite a bit of unnecessary redundency that makes it hard to follow and debug.
- You have grids of JTextFields, all of which can and should be replaced by three JTables, one for Meat, one for Chicken, and one for "other things".
- You use null layouts and absolute positioning, something that seems to a newbie an easier way to create complex GUI's, but in the long run is the most difficult way to create, maintain and upgrade these. You're far better off learning about and using the layout managers, including nesting JPanels each with its own layout.
- Any time I see variables named something12, something13, something14, something15, something16, something17, something18, ... I think that most of this can be replaced by an array or a collection such as an ArrayList, or in your case (as noted above), a JTable whose model is based in a collection.
- Each one of your table entries should likely be in its own class.
- I stand by my original recommendation that you should not have any of your classes inherit from the main GUI as this will lead to non-workable code.
- Also, your JFrame should not launch another JFrame, but rather the getProfitButton should launch a modal JDialog.

---

**Edit**
For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TableEg extends JPanel {
   private static final String[] ROW_TITLES = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
         "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
   MyTableModel tableModel = new MyTableModel(ROW_TITLES);
   private JTable table;

   public TableEg() {
      table = new JTable(tableModel) {
         @Override
         public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
            JComponent renderer = (JComponent) super.getCellRenderer(row,
                  column);
            boolean enabled = (Boolean) table.getValueAt(row, 0);
            renderer.setEnabled(enabled);
            return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
         }
      };
      table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseReleased(e);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                  table.repaint();
               }
            });
         }
      });

      JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
      scrollpane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(table.getPreferredSize());

      JButton getSumButton = new JButton(new GetSumAction("Get Sum", tableModel));
      JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
      southPanel.add(getSumButton);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TableEg mainPanel = new TableEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
   private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = { "Selected", "Name", "Number" };

   public MyTableModel(String[] rowTitles) {
      super(COLUMN_NAMES, 0);
      for (int i = 0; i < rowTitles.length; i++) {
         Object[] rowData = { Boolean.FALSE, rowTitles[i], Integer.valueOf(0) };
         addRow(rowData);
      }
      Object[] rowData = { Boolean.FALSE, "", Integer.valueOf(0) };
      addRow(rowData);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
      if (column == 0) {
         return true;
      }

      if (column == 1) {
         return row >= getRowCount() - 1;
      }

      if (column > 1) {
         return ((Boolean) getValueAt(row, 0)).booleanValue();
      }
      return super.isCellEditable(row, column);
   }

   @Override
   public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
      switch (columnIndex) {
      case 0:
         return Boolean.class;
      case 1:
         return String.class;
      case 2:
         return Integer.class;
      }
      return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
   }
}

class GetSumAction extends AbstractAction {

   private MyTableModel tableModel;

   public GetSumAction(String name, MyTableModel tableModel) {
      super(name);
      this.tableModel = tableModel;
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
         Object value = tableModel.getValueAt(i, 2);
         if (value != null) {
            sum += ((Integer) value).intValue();
         }
      }
      String text = "Number of days: " + sum;
      String title = "Number of Days";
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((JButton) evt.getSource(), text, title,
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but when it come to me when I try split the code that I written. I get confused.                                                             please look at my code

Comment: @user3250029: please see edit to answer. And you should not follow Roudy's advice about inheritance as it is not applicable to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to divide your code into methods, that would make your code more clear. 
As for inheritance, you can only modify variables that are in the parent class from the child class if those variable are :
.Data members
.Their visibility is set to protected 
Here is an example

```
public class Parent{
protected JButton button; 
protected int something; 
protected String whatever;
//^Those are the data members
public Parent(){//Constructor
//some code here
}

//more code
}//end of parent class

public class Child extends Parent{
private int randomstuff;
private String morerandomDatamembers;
public Child(){
super();
}

public void modify(){
something=3;
whatever="yayyy it worked";

         }
}
```

protected data members can only be accessed by the children of some class. 
EDIT- Inheritance can be used in specific cases. You can still modify data members of some class from a different class. Every method should have getters and setters. 
Example:

```
public class Car{
private int ModelNumber; 
private String CarName; 

public Car(int ModelNum,String name){
ModelNumber=ModelNum;
CarName=name;

}
public int getModelNum(){//First getter
return ModelNumber;
}
public void setModelNum(int ModelNum){//First setter
ModelNumber=ModelNum;
}
public String getCarName(){//Second getter;
return CarName;
}
public void setCarName(String Car){
CarName=Car;
}
}
public class Company{
private Car car;
public Company(Car c){
car=c;

}
public void modify(){
car.setModelNum(123);
car.setCarName("Ferrari");
System.out.println("Being so awesome,Roudy will let me try his Ferrari");

}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I'm getting the idea. However I'm having hard time understanding if I have a GUI class as Parent and I want to use the ActionListener, ItemListener, etc.  please look at my code.